# ffmpeg redirect stdout and stderr to each file and both to another in correct order

Tags: io-redirection, ffmpeg

Running a simple `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi out.mp4 -loglevel info
```

I want the following result:

`stdout` to both `stdout.log` and `both.log`
`stderr` to both `stderr.log` and `both.log`

The important thing also, is that the process doesn't have any delay, so the error lines go in the right places in the middle of stdout.

I've tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi out.mp4 1>(tee stdout.log >>both.log) 2>(tee stderr.log >>both.log)
```

It's important that works with all shells not only `bash` or `ksh`.

Comment: Didn't ffmpeg come with the ability to write its out and errors right into a file with no help from the shell?

Comment: ffmpeg doesn't log anything to stdout. It can only be used to pipe media data for another consumer.

Comment: @Gyan According to https://forum.puppylinux.com/viewtopic.php?t=9422 `ffmpeg` can produce both streams, what can't is to output the encoded file to stdout or stderr. But this is not what I want to do. What I want is to be able to have separate and combined `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: @Gyan could you point out the source code that prints these lines to console? `frame=  677 fps= 59 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:27.08 bitrate=N/A`

Comment: @Gyan whether ffmpeg logs to stdout/stderr or stderr only depends on the operating system, Windows versions log everything to stderr I think but Linux and MAC versions split it.

Comment: No, ffmpeg logs ONLY to stderr on any OS this is because media output can be piped to stdout so media and logs can't be allowd to mix. The line you pasted is a stats report. You can add `-progress FILENAME` to save these to a file in real-time.

Comment: @Gyan that doesn't work with `2024-01-01-git-e1c1dc8347-full_build-www.gyan.dev`, at least in PowerShell. Still sends stats to console.

Comment: I didn't say progress will *divert* the stats. Add `-nostats` to suppress stats line on stderr.

Comment: The MAC and Linux versions of ffmpeg don't work that way. They split the stats and progress to stdout and errors to stderr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150668/discussion-between-smeterlink-and-gyan).

Comment: stderr is hardcoded in the code.